# How to check whether a URL redirects to another page or not in PHP?

Tags: php, redirect, curl, boolean

What I want to see is whether the url entered by the user redirects to another page in PHP. I do not want to see where it redirects to, but just whether it redirects to another page or not.

Here's what I'm currently trying to use:

```
<?php
  echo "Redirect check";
  $ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com/');
  curl_exec($ch);
  $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  if ($code === 301 || $code === 302 || $code === 303 || $code === 307) {
    $redirect = true;
  }else{
    $redirect = false;
  }
?>
```

However, when I run this, it redirects me to yahoo.com after showing "redirect check" for a few moments.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the BODY when you are checking only the headers. Just send a `HEAD` request. Also you dont need to redirect.  So add the following options before `curl_exec`.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
```

See [example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HcLcTk)

Comment: Yep. It works now. I should have refered to the curl function in the php manual. Thanks a bunch :D